# Magento 2 : How to Add Custom Header

Tags: magento2, theme, custom, header

I am trying to add a custom header in Magento 2. I am creating my custom theme and add custom header page customeheader.phtml but header is not show.

[image: this is my code]

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add custom header then you just add this code into `Magento_Theme / layout / default.xml`

```
<referenceBlock name="header.container" remove="true" />
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
    <block  class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="top.header" template="Magento_Theme::customheader.phtml" before="header.container"/>
</referenceContainer>      
<move element="minicart" destination="top.header" />
```

And create `customheader.phtml` in `Magento_Theme / templates / customheader.phtml`

Hope it's help you !

Answer (score 3):

**default.xml**

```
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
     <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" 
            name="Custom_header" 
            template="Magento_Theme::html/customheader.phtml" 
            before="main.content"/> </referenceContainer> 
          <move element="navigation.sections" destination="Custom_header"/>      
          <move element="top.search" destination="Custom_header"/>
          <move element="minicart" destination="Custom_header"/>
          <move element="currency" destination="Custom_header"/>
          <move element="logo" destination="Custom_header"/>         
          <move element="skip_to_content" destination="Custom_header"/>
```

...

Answer (score 3):

Apart from above answers

I would like to add parent entities `<page><body>` for the default.xml file.
This is basically for the newcomers like me, because without this `page` and `body` our file will not reflected on the frontend.

here is my updated default.xml file

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="header.container" remove="true" />
        <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
            <block  class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="top.header" template="Magento_Theme::customheader.phtml" before="header.container"/>
        </referenceContainer>      
        <move element="minicart" destination="top.header" />
    </body>
</page>
```